# How do I run my code after the default page fault handler of windows has done execution?

Tags: x86, masm, osdev

For some reason I want to run my code *after* the page fault handler of windows has executed to ensure the page is now located in physcial memory. I used code below as the new int 0E handler:

```
    pushfd                      // eflags
    push cs
    call __Next
__Next:
    add dword ptr [esp], 0x0E           // eip
    push dword ptr [esp + 0x0C]         // error code
    jmp OldInt0EHandler
    // After the int 0e has run, EIP returns here.
    // TODO: add code here after the code has done
    add esp, 4
    iretd
```

But I get BSOD when I replace the handler with my new one. How do I do it right?

Comment: As soon as you modify the interrupt handler, the Windows kernel patch protection will trigger the BSOD, so I don't think this is possible. What exactly do you need this for?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to disable Windows kernel patch protection in order to do this. Otherwise, it will trigger the BOSD for (obvious) security reasons.